# Confusion in Python file execution

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pygame

System: Anaconda 2.7, Ubuntu 14.04.

I have a repository that needs both pygame and tensorflow to run.

I installed both.

Pygame does not get imported in simple `python` command. Instead, when I execute file via `/usr/bin/python` then I can import `pygame` succesfully.

But `tensorflow` works in `python` environment only and not in the `/usr/bin/python`
environment.

So, my code does not run. Error messages are ....unable to export.

Please help in resolving this issue. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: sounds like a path problem.  from each directory check which version of python you are using `python --version`

Comment: You need to install both using the same environment. Ie, same virtualenv

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I didn't gt it, plz give some commands so that I could follow. thanks.

Comment: All commands are here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html